# Deep link not working in Android 12 after publish assetlinks.json to domain and also put autoverify true in intent filter Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-deep-link

I know this question is asked before but I didn't find any correct answer that solve my issue

Deep link is working on android 11 or lower device but not working in android 12 device

Here example.com is for understanding

Pls check below code for open activity by deep link

```
<activity
            android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I also put meta data thing for deep link

```
<meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements"/>

<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">[{\"include\": \"https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"}]</string>
```

I also check that assetlinks.json file is valid or not by using this link

```
https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls
```

And there is no error that shows the json file is incorrect

Our assetlinks.json file is like this

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "example.com",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["9C:BC:79:E2:77:18:E4:23:F9:5B:B2:5A:...",
      "E4:37:19:8A:52:A9:6E:7C:A0:DE:62:FA:..",
      "15:39:35:57:FB:8E:A9:40:84:8C:3E:E7:..."
    ]
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "example.com.developement",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["9C:BC:79:E2:77:18:E4:23:F9:5B:B2:5A:5A:9E:..", 
"15:39:35:57:FB:8E:A9:40:84:8C:3E:E7:DF:9B:..."]
  }
},{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "example.com.qa",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["9C:BC:79:E2:77:18:E4:23:F9:5B:B2:5A:5A:9E..",
"15:39:35:57:FB:8E:A9:40:84:8C:3E:E7:DF:9B:6D:..."
    ]
  }
}]
```

WE get our sha256 key from google play console -> App integrity -> App signing
and from android studio
gradle -> gradle signingReport

Pls give suggestions what we're doing wrong, This is not working in android 12 device it's open the link in default browser but working in android 11 or lower device

Comment: What type of build are you testing this on?

Comment: release and debug, not working in any one of this

Comment: deep links verification would only work if you are using the same build for which you've added sha-256 in `assetlinks.json`

Comment: yes i'm using the same build which sha256 define in assetlinks.json

Comment: Try this manual verification https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#manual-verification

Comment: i tried that but in verify-app-links command it's show that it's Unknown command: verify-app-links

Comment: all other adb command works but not that

Comment: `adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify PACKAGE_NAME` are you sure you're testing on a Andriod 12 device, because I tried and it works fine.

Comment: ok, let's me try again

Comment: it's working now thanks for the support and guidance

Comment: @Praveen This did the trick for me. I was locally testing with an APK hence with another signature. I simply had to launch the Java Keytool command to retrieve the correct SHA-256 fingerprint and add it in my assetlinks.json. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase deep linking url host `exmple.page.link` then change it to `domain.com` where your `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` file locate.